# What parentheses and tildes mean in IPA / phonology chart

Tags: phonology, ipa

Why some symbols in phonology charts are put in parentheses or brackets, such as [`(z)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology), or [`[ɲ]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chara_language), and why there is a tilde `~` in some places, such as [`dz [dʒ ~ dz]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandawe_language). Wondering what that means exactly, if it just means that the sound represented by their alphabet `dz` is within the range between `dʒ` and `dz` in IPA terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all symbols used in phonological and phonetic descriptions are letters of the IPA. The symbol "~" typically means "alternates with", for example "a~æ" could be that either *a* or *æ* would be possible in a given context (i.e. the sounds are in free variation). It also can be used to refer to contextual variation, for example "The plural suffix, *s ~ z ~ ɨz*...". Square brackets canonically refer to phonetic values, so [dz ~ dʒ] would be that the thing in question (perhaps phonemic /dz/) is realised either as phonetic [dz] or as phonetic [dʒ]). It does not mean "some value intermediate between", it means "either this value or that value". There is no notation for talking of ranges of realization that are finer-grained than two similar transcriptions. If the realization of a sound was "anything between [dz] and [dʒ]", you would have to say that in words.

Parenthesis has two different meanings. In a list of phonemes, it implies that there is something marginal about the item in parentheses, for example one might list "(x)" in a phoneme chart of English, since there are a few words which some people pronouns with the velar fricative [x] (Bach, loch, Chanukah, chutzpah, Khalil). However, in writing a rule, it means "0 or 1 occurrences of", so "a→b/_(c)d" means "a becomes b when followed by d with zero or one occurrence of c intervening".

Comment: A cleaner way to say "0 or 1 occurrences of" might be "optional", as in the syllable structure (C)V "a vowel preceded by an optional consonant".